# Update response body content using HttpClientFeature

Tags: kotlin, ktor

Using a `HttpClientFeature` implementation with `responsePipeline.intercept` seems the right way to change an HTTP response.

However, I do not understand how to update the response body. Especially I don't understand how to wrap the new `HttpResponse` to be passed in to `proceedWith`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `HttpResponseContainer` to proceed with a new response body:

```
client.responsePipeline.intercept(HttpResponsePipeline.Transform) { (info, body) ->
    val newBody = "test"
    proceedWith(HttpResponseContainer(info, newBody))
}
```